# No mapping found even though it exists in the Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have controller `EnvironmentController` as follows

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard/environments")
public class EnvironmentController {
    /*
    *Other methods
    */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/${envId}/addKey/${region}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String addKey(@PathVariable("envId") Long envId,
            @PathVariable("region") String region, HttpSession session) {
        if (session.getAttribute("loggedin") != null
                && (Boolean) session.getAttribute("loggedin") == true) {
            DUser user = (DUser) session.getAttribute("user");
            List<Role> roles = roleDao.getRoles(userDao.getUserByEmail(user
                    .getEmail()));
            // other codes
        } else {
            session.invalidate();
            return "{unauthorized}";
        }
        return "{}";
    }
}
```

In my JSP page I am posting the data using jQuery, the code being.

```
$("#create").on('click',function() {
    alert($("#region").val());
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dashboard/environments/${envId}/addKey/"+$("#region").val(),
        data : $("#region").val(),
        success : success
    });
});
```

RootContext of the web app being `myapp`

I can see in the web browser console that the data is `POST`ed to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/dashboard/environments/2/addKey/us-east-1`.

Also in the logs I can see the following
`INFO: Mapped "{[/dashboard/environments/${envId}/addKey/${region}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.controller.EnvironmentController.addKey(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)`

When I do `POST` to the url, it get warning

`WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/dashboard/environments/2/addKey/us-east-1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`

I cannot figure out why is `addKey` method is not called when I post data to it and that the mapping is incorrect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request mapping is wrong. The path variable placeholders should not contain `$`. So the correct form is `@RequestMapping(value = "/{envId}/addKey/{region}", ...)`.

Comment: So true, how did I miss that. Thanks.